# Sanitising dev and master branches

Tags: git, merge

I'd like some advice on how could I approach the following situation:

We have the common branches setup with `master` and `development`, where ideally develompent gets merged into master on each release. Due to difficulties in the past months, now the situation is:

- `master` contains all changes existing in `development`
- most of the previous mentioned changes, exist in different commits on each branch (with different hashes) - this is due to cherry-picking/rebasing commits from `development` to `master`
- Apart from the changes that exists in both branches, `development` has changes that need to be merged in master (for the current release) but it also has many others that shouldn't be merged in (as they are not ready for release yet)

I'm looking for a way to clean up things a bit, so at least I get to the point where all the commits that were duplicated by cherry-picking/rebasing are merged back in master, so development has only the changes mentioned in the 3º bullet point.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This looks like bad branching etiquette.  If you suspected that you needed to do work which should not be merged from `development` to `master`, then the more prudent thing to do would have been to branch again off `development` and hold this extra work there.  I don't have a clear answer, because your repo looks like a real mess to me.

Comment: Well, it's indeed a bit messy, that's why I'm asking for advice. Thanks for your suggestion though!

Comment: If you already cherry picked only some of the `development` commits, then I suspect that you will have to continue cherry picking to finish the job.